# why the check uncheck doesn't show/hide the content?

Tags: jquery

```
http://gomoxy.com/una/edmontonautoloans/credit-application.php
```

my jquery code:

```
$("#callback_toggle").is(':checked')){
    $("#txthiden").hide();
    }else{
   $("#txthiden").show();
}
```

when i checked the checkbox, i want to hide the content which in `txthiden` div. vice versa. the default state is unchecked.and the  the content in `txthiden` div is showing. why my code doesn't work. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/ACnn4/1/

**code**

```
$("#callback_toggle").on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $("#txthiden").hide();
    } else {
        $("#txthiden").show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

change:

```
$("#callback_toggle").is(':checked')){
```

to:

```
if ($("#callback_toggle").is(':checked')) {
```

Comment: +1 but also note that need to check any event on the checkbox i.e. click or change `:)`

Answer (score 0):

[Obligatory rant on misspellings and table based layouts in `<div>`s here]

You need to use an event handler for this. Your code was trying to do the toggling in DOMready, not when the checkbox is toggled.

```
$('#callback_toggle').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        ("#txthiden").hide();
    } else {
        ("#txthiden").show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this should work.

Probably this would be the simplest one. [See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vJ8bN/)

```
$("#callback_toggle").click(function() {
        $("#txthiden").toggle();
});​
```

This one works as well

```
$("#callback_toggle").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $("#txthiden").hide();
    } else {
        $("#txthiden").show();
    }
});​
```